# mdf File accidentally deleted

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello Stack overflow community I'm really in trouble and I need your help

I accidentally deleted an MDF file of my current database and now my database does't work
how can I deal with that and I have no recent BAKUP
My database size is 10000 ko

Comment: I would probably go with rum, but you might be a whiskey person. OK, on a more serious note: What kind of environment are you in? Is this just a desktop PC? Is it a work environment? Do you have an infrastructure team? Was the database on a VM? Basically, is there anyone, or any process, that might have done some other kind of backup, (for exmaple, an image of an entire VM)?

Comment: its a work environment , the database is in VM with windows server

Comment: Ask your infrastructure team if they are backing up the VM.

Comment: Oh and... just in case... did you check the recycle bin for the file? Haha. You never know!

Comment: @allmhuran I did it but suddenly there is no file, is there any software that recovers properly big size files

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have experience with that.

Comment: On the plus side, if you were able to delete the MDF, the database cannot have been online. If it's been offline for a while, even an "old" sql backup or VM backup might have an up to date copy of the file.

Comment: okkk thanx a lot